# What OOD principles could assist in optimizing memory usage?

Tags: java, oop, memory, model-view-controller, ooad

I'm trying to design (say in java), Four In A Row game using the MVC pattern.

The FourInARowModel class stands for the model and looks something like this:

```
public class FourInARowModel extends Observable{

//fileds
private boolean turn = true;
private int discsNum = 0;
GameState gameState = null;
private Player firstPlayer, secondPlayer; 
private Board board;
private Cell lastCellChanged;

//methods   

}
```

Suppose there could be an implementation (server game for instance) 
s.t there could be multiple instances of the FourInARowModel class. Which pattern/"trick" would allow the best optimization for memory usage? (assume this class is heavy and I want to create a few instances as I can of it).

What should I use in this case? Caching/Pooling? make it Immutable class? Anything else?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: OOD is not really about memory usage. You often sacrifice small amounts of performance for better design. And what kind of pattern would be good for you depends primarily on how you use this class which is not obvious from your question. a) why should there be multiple instances of your model (are there multiple games at once?) b) what class is responsible to create / manage / destroy the model? Depending on the usage in that class you can think of a way how to control your instances.

Comment: a) Yes. The could be a server playing this game with many users at once (different games).  b)The class that responsible for that is ofcourse the controller class while the "command" is given from the view class (see MVC).

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root oft all evil" -http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization